# jQuery .toogleClass function to toggle elements class and do something during the event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I'm trying to use jQuery toogleClass to switch elements.
I want to switch from a follow to an unfollow icon and do something during each click (like ajax call, alert, or something else). So what i intend to do is to use `toogleClass(function(){})` to implement this functionality.

HTML:

```
    <a class="follow button tiny circle">
        <i class="fa-2x fa fa-eye"></i>
    </a>
```

JS:

```
    $("div.up-right a").click(function(){

    $(this).find("i").toggleClass(function(){
        if($(this).parent().hasClass("follow")){
            $(this).parent().removeClass( "follow" ).addClass( "unfollow" );
            return "fa-eye-slash";
        }else {
            $(this).parent().removeClass( "unfollow" ).addClass( "follow" );
            return "fa-eye";
        }

});
```

What I want to do is when I click, I want to change class in parent (follow<->unfollow) and (fa-eye to fa-eye-slash) and to do something.

Please take a look on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hks9g8bv/)

Note: I'm following this [jquery .toggleClass doc](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a simple toggle function and give it an element, classname to set and classname to unset. If the parent has the class 'follow', you can set 'unfollow' and unset 'follow'. Same goes for the child. Just make sure to pass the right element to the function.

```
$(".up-right a").click(function(){
    $(this).hasClass('follow') ? toggle($(this), 'unfollow', 'follow')
                               : toggle($(this), 'follow', 'unfollow');
    $(this).hasClass('follow') ? toggle($(this).find('i'), 'fa-eye', 'fa-eye-slash')
                               : toggle($(this).find('i'), 'fa-eye-slash', 'fa-eye');
});

function toggle (el, set, unset) {
    $(el).addClass(set);
    $(el).removeClass(unset);
}
```